# what is the alternative of 'register' in e_driver.register(eventListener);

Tags: c#, selenium

I previously used WebEventListner in selenium using java but my workplaces uses c#. I am getting an error at 'register' e_driver.register(eventListener);

can some please help in c#, please.

```
namespace TestFramework.Utils
{
    public class WebEventListener
    {
        public static void beforeNavigateTo(String url, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before navigating to: '" + url + "'");
        }

        public static void afterNavigateTo(String url, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Navigated to:'" + url + "'");
        }
}

 [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void InitializeOnce()
        {
            PropertiesCollection.driver = BrowserFactory.PrepareBrowser(Config.browser);
            driver = PropertiesCollection.driver;

            e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
            eventListener = new WebEventListener();
            e_driver.register(eventListener);
            driver = e_driver;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is fundamentally different in its syntax from Java. Since [C# natively supports events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events) in its syntax, the .NET implementation of `EventFiringWebDriver` leverages those. Additionally, the event names will differ, in keeping with making the .NET bindings feel "natural" to .NET developers. What you want is something like the following:

```
public IWebDriver CreateEventFiringDriver(IWebDriver driver)
{
    // Assume driver is a valid IWebDriver instance.
    var eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
    eventDriver.Navigating += NavigatingEventHandler;
    eventDriver.Navigated += NavigatedEventHandler;
    return eventDriver;
}

private void NavigatingEventHandler(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before navigating to: '" + e.Url + "'");
}

private void NavigatedEventHandler(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Navigated to:'" + e.Url + "'");
}
```